# How to change all negative values in dataframe(pandas) to NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, negative-number

I have a dataframe with 4 numerical columns and 1 column with string values.
One of the columns contains several negative values which I need to replace with NaN value.

I've tried mask method
`df.mask(df_iris_new < 0)`, but the error was that I `can't compare str and int`,

so I tried:

`df.mask(df_iris_new['column1'] < 0)`

and then it replaced the whole row with NaN values, whereas I need to change only this particular negative value from the first column, as all the rest are positive values that I need.

And the other question is should I somehow exclude the string column from the method?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to find the numeric columns

```py
cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols] < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is one column with string and you know the column name, then you can do:

```
numeric_cols = df.columns.difference(['string_col'])
df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].mask(df[numeric_cols].lt(0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice another way of doing it.